# Does the default xWiki REST API support JWT tokens? xWiki SAS

Tags: jwt, spring-oauth2, xwiki

Hello everyone :smiley:

Is there a way for the xWiki default API to understand requests with JWT tokens?

The idea is to make requests to the default API of the Wiki adding JWT tokens, in order to allow a default user to perform operations with the Wiki and to be authenticated and authorized to perform actions such as: Create pages, create objects from pages, etc.

Whenever I make a request to create a page, I get the following error:

WARN nticationFailureLoggerListener - Authentication failure with login [null]. (Logs from the Wiki)

"code":401,"contactEmail":null,"description":"The request requires user authentication","homeRef":"/","reasonPhrase":"Unauthorized","uri":"http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2"}  (The response I get from the petition via Insomnia).

Any help or documentation would be of great support.

Thank you very much.

I have my Keycloak configured and the SSO authentication is working fine, I have modified the xwiki.cfg and xwiki.properties files and I have downloaded the PlugIns from:

OpenID Connect Authenticator
OpenID Connect Provider

https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/OpenID%20Connect/OpenID%20Connect%20Authenticator/